# postgres function help needed

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write an Postgres function and I need to the following:

```
DECLARE ids bigint;

Begin
    -- save all john's ids. But that seems to save only one id. It may return several
    select id_partner INTO ids from tb_partners WHERE name like 'john%';

    -- Do a lot of things

    -- only after doing things, and that may include add new johns, I need to delete the ones saved at the start of the function.

    DELETE FROM tb_partners WHERE id_partner IN (ids);
```

The problems is that only delete one id, even if it have several to be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ids` . . . well, there are probably more than one of them.  Use a temporary table:

```
create temporary table temp_johns_ids as
    select id_partner
    from tb_partners 
    where name like 'john%';

-- Do a lot of things

-- only after doing things, and that may include add new johns, I need to delete the ones saved at the start of the function.

delete from tb_partners
    where id_partner in (select id from temp_johns_ids);
```

Comment: Do I need to delete this temporary table afterwards or it's in memory? because I need to run this function several times from time to time.

Comment: @FabioPereira . . . That is a little complicated, especially if transactions are involved.  The simplest is just to drop the table at the end of the function.